# How to make my custom IDocHostUIHandler take effect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm using VS2010, MFC project. My task is to customize the webbrowser control, for example, disable context menu.

I wrote my custom IDocHostUIHandler( eg. MyCustomUIHandler: public IDocHostUIHandler) to implement this interface. And I known that, I can using ICustomDoc::SetUIHandler to make my implement take effect. But the problem is, before calling SetUIHandler, the webbrowser control must have a Document. In other words, my implement will take effect only when user navigate the second page.(After the Document of the first page is ready, SetUIHandler called)

The msdn document said that the implement will take effect automatically!(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  But I don't know how to do that. Should I change some configuration, or write some code in initialization? Can someone give me a guide step by step? Thanks in advance:)  PS: I am just a MFC & COM newbie ~~

(I just wrote my Class MyCustomUIHandler: public IDocHostUIHandler, in custom.h, custom.cpp.)